# flex4 list and layout dragging animation

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop, flex4

I found a blog about the list drag-drop animation:[drag-list-animation-demo](http://rialitycheck.com/demos/spark/layoutdemo.html), the blog is here:
[blog about the drag animation](http://www.rialitycheck.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/3/3/Animating-Spark-List-Items)
Unfortunately, This blog has no source code, so anyone know how to implement like the effect?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the best way to do this is to implement your custom layout basing on info from post or contact it's author directly. I had the same problem a year ago, spent a day trying to reproduce the exact behavior, but didn't get quite close to original.